# Apply same function autocomplete to multiple input boxes javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete javascript function that I don't know how to use for multiple input boxes on the same page. I have tried a lot of things and for some reason it breaks the script here is the code and how I am doing it now..

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        SearchText();
    });
  function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({

             select:function(event, ui){
              window.location.href = '/Products/ProductInfoCenter.aspx?partnum=' + ui.item.value;
           },
            source: function (request, response, ui) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/test.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'PartNumber':'" + document.getElementById('txtPartNum').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                       response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert(err.message);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

And the input boxes...

```
   <input type="text" id="txtPartNum" class="autosuggest" />
   <input type="text" id="txtPartNum" class="autosuggest" />
```

of course this does not work though..

Thank you and please help

Comment: Your first problem is that you have two elements with the same `id` which is invalid

Comment: i tried multiple other ways of fixing it and I don't know any other solution

Comment: So what exactly is broken with your page?

Comment: Did you try changing the second input id to something like txtPartNum2?

Comment: using `"{'PartNumber':'" + document.getElementById('txtPartNum').value + "'}",` then duplicate IDs could be your issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/524V2/

Comment: yeah it doesn't work i have tried changing everything to make it work with two javascripts but it doesnt work.... I wanted to use the .This but that also failed the way i used it as well

Comment: Just FYI - your error handler won't work.

Comment: @RobH how do i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As i see it, your code should be:

```
data: {PartNumber: request.term },
```

And of course fix your invalid HTML markup, removing any duplicate IDs.

Comment: what do i name the input boxes when i am using this.value

Comment: `this` refers to the current input i guess.

Comment: So i did what you said and here is the results  http://www.bivar.com/test.aspx it breaks the javascript all together.

Comment: I just checked, maybe use instead: `request.term` (sorry, i don't know autocomplete plugin)

Comment: Following your link, are you aware you are not loading jQuery there, nor autocomplete plugin?!

Comment: Yes i am... try again this is how it was before

Comment: @user3481843 I don't know what to check... In your page, you are not including jQuery nor jQuery UI to support autocomplete, so what i'm supposed to try???

Comment: If @user3481843 you want to use jQueryUI autocomplete, you must load jQuery and jQueryUI file in your webpage.

Comment: Im sorry try again... haha

Comment: So please try now: `data: {PartNumber: request.term },` and please REMOVE duplicates IDs. And if still not working, edit your site to let me check with updated code WHY it is not working

Comment: This throws server side error, of course i cannot help you more on this (i'm not a ASP guy): `{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: PartNumber.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()...`

Answer (score 0):

Change your script as -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        SearchText();
    });
  function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({

             select:function(event, ui){
              window.location.href = '/Products/ProductInfoCenter.aspx?partnum=' + ui.item.value;
           },
            source: function (term, add) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/test.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: term,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                       add(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert(err.message);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and you can not use same id on one page. Change your html as -

```
<input type="text" class="autosuggest" />
<input type="text" class="autosuggest" />
```